# Search result inconsistencies

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In Elastic 5.5.1, I've got two indexes, both have the same data in them, 608k records. When I run a `multi_match` query against each index, I retrieve different number of results between them.  When comparing the search results to the original source of data this is what I get:

```
_______________________________
|    Source      | Rows Found |
|  ------------  | ---------- |
| SQL            | 1300       |
| Elastic Index 1| 503        |
| Elastic Index 2| 626        |
-------------------------------
```

Queries:

```
SQL:
SELECT field1 FROM Table WHERE field1 LIKE '78%'

ELASTIC:
/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "query": "78",
            "fields": [
              "field1"
            ]
          }          
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Index 1:

```
PUT test_index_one
{
  "mappings": {
    "field1": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index 2:

```
PUT test_index_two
{
  "mappings": {
    "field1": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, why would I not receive the same number of hits using the same query against the same dataset, although different index?  I know scoring can be different across shards which is where the `search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch` parameter comes into play, but is there something I may be missing here?